# Bringing to a common date

Tags: date, go

I would like to comapre two dates which are strings: `"2021-05-30T15:00:00"`, `"2021-05-30"` and return true when the day is the same. I want to ignore hour.

```
"2021-05-30T15:00:00" => 2021-05-30  
"2021-05-30" => 2021-05-30  
2021-05-30 == 2021-05-30  // true
```

To achieve this I made two functions which format date. `timeParser` is for date with hour. `simplifyDate` is for string date without hour.

```
const dateFormat = "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
const simpleDateFormat = "2006-01-02"

const departureTime = "2021-05-30T15:00:00"
const startDate = "2021-05-30"


func timeParser(format, value string) time.Time {
    parsed, err := time.Parse(format, value)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("timeParser Error: ", err)
    }
    return parsed
}

func simplifyDate(value string) time.Time {
    parsed, err := time.Parse(dateFormat, value)
    parsed.Format(simpleDateFormat)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("timeParser Error: ", err)
    }
    return parsed
}


isStartDate := simplifyDate(departureTime) == timeParser(simpleDateFormat, startDate) // return false 

fmt.Println("simplifyDate(departureTime)", simplifyDate(departureTime)) //2021-05-30 15:00:00 +0000 UTC
fmt.Println("timeParser(simpleDateFormat, startDate)", timeParser(simpleDateFormat, startDate)) // 2021-05-30 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

In `timeParser` and `simplifyDate` I try to format date into  DD-MM-YYYY as `simpleDateFormat = "2006-01-02"` is. But I get date with hours and zeros at the end like `2021-05-30 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, `2021-05-30 15:00:00 +0000 UTC`. Can you point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing the dates, you don't need to format them to compare them. The `time.Time` type has some methods that will help you here.

Try something like this:

```golang
// time1 and time2 are your raw time.Time values
return (time1.Year() == time2.Year()) && (time1.YearDay() == time2.YearDay())
```

[Time.Year](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Year)

> Year returns the year in which t occurs.

[Time.YearDay](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.YearDay)

> YearDay returns the day of the year specified by t, in the range [1,365] for non-leap years, and [1,366] in leap years.

Answer (score 1):

Given the circumstances, it seems you could just do string comparison:

```
package main

func compare(s, t string) bool {
   if len(s) > 10 {
      s = s[:10]
   }
   if len(t) > 10 {
      t = t[:10]
   }
   return s == t
}

func main() {
   for _, each := range []struct {
      s, t string
      res bool
   } {
      {"", "", true},
      {"", "2021-05-30T15:00:00", false},
      {"2021-05-30T15:00:00", "", false},
      {"2021-05-30T15:00:00", "2021-05-30", true},
   } {
      if compare(each.s, each.t) == each.res {
         println("pass")
      } else {
         println("fail")
      }
   }
}
```